# Select List is not in Group By Clause and Contains non-aggregated column

Tags: mysql

```
    SELECT JSON_OBJECT( 'additionalGroupId', agData.aguid, 'name', 
        agData.name, 'userName', CONCAT(agData.firstname, agData.lastname), 
        'userId', agData.uuid, 'vessel', agData.vessel  ) as data 
    FROM ( SELECT ag.aguid, ag.id, ag.name, u.uuid, 
           u.firstname, u.lastname, 
         ( SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG( JSON_OBJECT('vesselId', v.vuid, 'vessel', 
           v.vessel, 'imoNumber', v.imoNumber)) FROM vessel v LEFT JOIN 
           additionalgroupvessels agva on agva.vesselId = v.id 
           WHERE agva.additionalGroupId = ag.id ) as vessel FROM additionalgroup 
           ag LEFT JOIN user u ON ag.userId = u.id WHERE ag.isDeleted = false ) agData 
    GROUP BY agData.aguid, agData.name, agData.uuid, agData.vessel;
```

This is my query and the error I am facing is -- GET API query error: `ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'agData.firsttname' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following command in mysql:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Comment: Instead of replacing the sqlmode

Comment: @coderzrule then don't 'accept' an answer 4 minutes after asking a question

Answer (score 0):

`agData.firstname, agData.lastname` Are nog in your `GROUP BY`, or with a simple example:

If you have: `SELECT a,min(b),c FROM mytable GROUP BY a`
You (should) get the same error because with the setting [ONLY_FULL_GROUP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) there is no way to know if you want the minimum value for c, or the maximum value, or any other aggregated value.

Solution is to add field c to the group by, (`SELECT a,min(b),c FROM mytable GROUP by a,c`)

or to add an aggregated function to field c. (`SELECT a,min(b),avg(c) FROM mytable GROUP BY a`)

and, of course, you also have the possibility to change the `sql_mode` setting. But the `sql_mode` setting was changed since Mysql8.0 with a purpose so, my advice, do not change that